# A project using jersey with maven and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, maven

I am creating a simple project to learn more about `jersey`, `hibernate-jpa-2.0-API`. 
I am not sure if I need to add Spring to this mix yet. I have created a model class and I have exposed an endpoint through `Jersey`. Now I want to find ways to retrieve data from the Model.

One of the possible options that I can think of is to create a service (using spring) which will get the data through `entityManager`. This requires hibernate core. Are there any other ways to retrieve the data such as using `hibernate-jpa` without using `spring`?

I also saw this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example/) a little late but are there alternatives to do this without the `hibernate config file`?

Thanks.

I added following files to try and experiment with hibernate.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        Configuration c = new Configuration();          
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml         
        return c.configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}

}
```

I also created a DAO with following

```
public class SimpleModelDAO {

private Session getCurrentSession() {       
    return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
}

public SimpleModelDAO() {}

public List<SimpleModel> getResults() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Session s = getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
    Criteria cr = s.createCriteria(SimpleModel.class);      
    // If testtype is not 5 then it is regular segment export       
    return cr.list();
}
}
```

However, right now the list returning 0 (I think its because the entity is not tied with hibernate). Is there a way to tie this?

Comment: adding c.addAnnotatedClass(SimpleModel.class); actually helped resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring, this is **easier** and **faster**. Just go to http://start.spring.io/ and select

- Web
- Jpa
- Maven project

Download and open project.

To implement REST read this tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

If you really need Jersey instead of default SPring Rest, then read:
http://geowarin.github.io/spring-boot/jersey/2014/01/31/a-simple-spring-boot-and-jersey-application.html

Or look at official way to integrate Jersey: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-jersey